# Clojure's thread does not show results in Emacs clojure-repl mode

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

I have this Clojure code that starts and executes a function.

```
(import [java.lang Thread])
(defn with-new-thread [f]
  (.start (Thread. f)))
(with-new-thread (fn [] (print "hi")))
```

However, when I run it in emacs in slime-repl mode (executed with `cider-jack-in`, there is nothing printed out, but nil returned.

[image]

With `lein real`, I got the expected output.

```
user=> (import [java.lang Thread])
java.lang.Thread
user=> (defn with-new-thread [f] (.start (Thread. f)))
#'user/with-new-thread
user=> (with-new-thread (fn [] (print "hello\n")))
hello
nil
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because the main thread in CIDER/Emacs binds the REPL output buffer to the `*out*` dynamic var. This is why you can see things in emacs.

However when you start a new thread, that binding doesn't exist. Fixing is simple enough - first create a function which will capture the current binding:

```
(def  repl-out *out*)
(defn prn-to-repl [& args]
  (binding [*out* repl-out]
    (apply prn args)))
```

Now, whenever you want to print from a different thread, use:

```
(prn-to-repl "hello")
```

And that's it. Hope this helps.